# PHP Session is not destroying after user logout

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to create an authentication mechanism for my PHP Application and I'm having difficulty destroying the session. I've tried unsetting the authentication token which was previously set within the session array and destroying the session through

`session_destroy`,

as well as resetting the session array completely before destroying the session. I'm calling the header function and going back to my index.php page at the end of the function calls. I've also tried

`session_write_close`

to handle closing the session. When I log the user out, I do a vardump of the session, and It shows no data present, however when I go back to the index.php page, I'm getting back the user authentication data. I also did a vardump of the Post data just to ensure I'm not somehow resubmitting the post authentication handler.

Any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: You don't have to use session_write_close().. normally for user authentication.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, make sure you're calling `session_start();` before calling `session_destroy();` because it will only issue a warning if you don't.

Also, from [PHP: session_destroy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

Comment: If you used named sessions don't forget to use session_name too!

Answer (score 2):

Also worth noting about PHP sessions, [`session_unset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) > [`session_destroy()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php);  <s>I do not know why.</s>  After reading the [PHP Manual entry on `session_destroy()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), it seems to only remove data within the current context, and not actually clear it from the flat session file, so if you didn't clear the cookie you could get it right back.  This seems highly counter-intuitive (as PHP often is), and might be the reason why I decided (and then promptly forgot the reason) years ago to always use [`session_unset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) over [`session_destroy()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Also, make sure your redirect is occurring after you do all this session nonsense, as PHP acts in ways which not all developers expect.  Best Practice, IMO, is to follow every `header('Location: ...');` call with a `die;`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the page isn't cached?

Write over the authentication token:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['varName'] = null;
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use only session_unset() then buggy IE still keeps data my suggestion is to use both.

Answer (score 0):

I would check what is sending the browser to the server using Fiddler and also check what information do you have stored in your session.save_path