# Session not destroy after logout in php

Tags: php

I have research a lot and I have yet to find the solution to my problem. I clik a link for the user to logout the user then is redirected to the login page. The problem is that when the user is redirected it still logged in. This is my code to logout the user.

```
session_start();
  $_SESSION = array(); //destroy all of the session variables
  unset($_SESSION['valid']);
  unset($_SESSION['userid']);
  unset($_SESSION['username']);
  session_destroy();
  Header("Location:login.php");
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Your unsets make no sense after `$_SESSION = array();`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `cookie` which holds user information? `print_r($_COOKIE);` to see.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684187/php-session-is-not-destroying-after-user-logout?rq=1

Comment: Also might want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370264/sessions-in-php-exists-after-destroying?rq=1

Comment: [`session_destroy()` example](http://php.net/session_destroy#refsect1-function.session-destroy-examples)

Comment: How are you checking whether the user is still logged in?

Comment: There are values after the print_r

Comment: @emurray: create a single several-lines script to reproduce the behaviour and show it to us. Here `session_destroy()` works as expected.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry I'm new to this and I don't quiet understand what you are traying to tell me.

Comment: @emurray: create trivial file from the scratch: that creates a session and fills it with data (just couple dummy strings are fine), and another one, that destroys it. And check if it works.

Comment: If you're using multiple session names, you may destroy one but not the other.

Comment: I finally solve it with the domain answer. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that both login and logout page's subdomains are the same

as the session's cookie is domain based by default unless you change that.

```
session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced similar problem and yes, i found that my cookies are set;
so simply adding following code helped me to get rid of it:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])):
setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-7000000, '/');
```

endif;